# Pharmaceutical grade phosphoric acid

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reference-request

I am looking for a specification for pharmaceutical grade phosphoric acid.

Comment: Will you confirm that you are looking for the actual USP specification for phosphoric acid?

Comment: here are tests for phosphoric acid to meet the specification http://www.pharmacopeia.cn/v29240/usp29nf24s0_m64570.html